# How many consecutive votes won't tag me spam?

Tags: discussion, support, voting

I saw there are two bronze badges available. One for 30 votes/day  and one for 40 votes/day so it's easy to earn them.

What is the minimum period allowed between consecutive votes? Such that, the behavior doesn't smell spammy?

Comment: Smell spammy? unless you are targetting a user its not against the rules..vote according to usefulness of the post

Comment: Okay. That means no cheating. :-)

Comment: If you vote naturally there will never be a problem in the first place. That is: vote on posts you stumble on, don't go looking for posts to vote on.

Comment: Remember that upvotes aren’t the only kind of votes, we need your downvotes too, and they count towards the badges. When I’ve wanted those badges it’s from mostly sitting on the front page in my tags and making a judgement on each Q (though some deserve neither + nor -), and on the As on Qs which interest me.

Comment: The badge is only there so you have an incentive to try out behaviors the system encourages. Trying to game the system to get the badge faster gets you the meaningless icon in your profile faster (W00T W00T!)... But robs you of the experience of learning said behavior.... Not the best of both worlds at all :p

Comment: Actually, behind the question that wasn't my question. Actually, I use the vote option rarely. I'll vote from now, but more. Voting takes some second to think, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a time requirement for voting but if there is, the system would just prevent you from voting too soon. For example, there IS a time minimum for flagging comments but it just shows a pop-up saying:

> You must wait 3 seconds before flagging another comment.

or something similar. You'll be slowed down if you go to fast, not punished.